# Javascript Tax Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, math, numbers

I'm trying to create a program that sums the three values of the array `var prices = [12.3, 20, 30.33];` together, and outputs both the sum and the total bill with tax of 7%.

Here is my HTML:

```
<p>Sum of numbers in array: <span id="sum"></span></p>

<p>Amount with 7% tax added: <span id="percent"></span></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

JS:

```
var numbers = [12.3, 20, 30.33];
var taxAmount = .07;

function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
}
function myFunction(item) {
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum);
}

function multiply(item) {
    document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum) * .07;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you were not calling the function

```js
var numbers = [12.3, 20, 30.33];
var taxAmount = .07;

function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
}
function myFunction(item) {
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum);
   document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum) * .07;
}
```

```html
<p>Sum of numbers in array: <span id="sum"></span></p>

<p>Amount with 7% tax added: <span id="percent"></span></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: if whichever answer you think is correct please mark it as a answer. so next time when someone also has same problem then can get their solution .

Answer (score 0):

You don't called the funtion and you need to sum the actual value with the tax of 7%.

```
numbers.reduce(getSum) + numbers.reduce(getSum) * .07
```

```js
var numbers = [12.3, 20, 30.33];
var taxAmount = .07;

function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
}
function myFunction(item) {
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum);
    document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum) + numbers.reduce(getSum) * .07;
}
```

```html
<p>Sum of numbers in array: <span id="sum"></span></p>

<p>Amount with 7% tax added: <span id="percent"></span></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```